# WebGL Unavailable, GPU Process unable to boot

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, gpu

I'm running Chrome 54.0.2840.87 on Windows 10. I have two GPUs: an Intel(R) HD Graphics 520, and a AMD Radeon R5 M335.

Up until a couple of weeks ago, WebGL was running just fine in chrome. Now, after not having changed any settings anywhere, WebGL is no longer available.

When trying to run a chrome experiment for example, I get a message saying that my graphics card does not seem to support WebGL. I know my graphics cards work fine (they have been updated with the latest drivers), plus WebGL runs perfectly in firefox. I know my GPUs have not been blacklisted (on either browser).

On `chrome:gpu`, I am told that WebGL is unavailable, and that the GPU process was unable to boot. When checking `chrome:flags` enabling or disabling WebGL no longer seems to be an option.

Enabling/disabling anything else that involves WebGL has not made any difference. Is there something else that can be done to get it working again? At what level is the issue? (The issue persists on Chrome Canary.) I am not the most technologically savvy person, but I've had no luck finding answers anywhere else.

The following is what I see on my `chrome:gpu` page:

**Graphics Feature Status**

> Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Flash: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Flash Stage3D: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration
>   unavailable
>
> Compositing: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Multiple Raster Threads: Unavailable
>
> Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
>
> Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> Video Encode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> VPx Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
>
> WebGL: Unavailable

**Driver Bug Workarounds**

> clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
>
> disable_d3d11
>
> disable_discard_framebuffer
>
> disable_dxgi_zero_copy_video
>
> disable_nv12_dxgi_video
>
> disable_framebuffer_cmaa
>
> exit_on_context_lost
>
> scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args

**Problems Detected**

> GPU process was unable to boot: GPU process launch failed.
>
> Disabled Features: all
>
> Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process
>   sandbox
>
> Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
>
> Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764,
>   349137
>
> Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
>
> Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
>
> Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
>
> Disable Direct3D11 on systems with AMD switchable graphics: 451420
>
> Applied Workarounds: disable_d3d11
>
> Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
>
> Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
>
> NV12 DXGI video hangs or displays incorrect colors on AMD drivers:
>   623029, 644293
>
> Applied Workarounds: disable_dxgi_zero_copy_video,
>   disable_nv12_dxgi_video
>
> Limited enabling of Chromium GL_INTEL_framebuffer_CMAA: 535198
>
> Applied Workarounds: disable_framebuffer_cmaa
>
> Native GpuMemoryBuffers have been disabled, either via about:flags or
>   command line.
>
> Disabled Features: native_gpu_memory_buffers

**Version Information**

> Data exported 11/7/2016, 2:09:57 PM
>
> Chrome version    Chrome/54.0.2840.87
>
> Operating system  Windows NT 10.0.14393
>
> Software rendering list version   11.12
>
> Driver bug list version   9.00
>
> ANGLE commit id   905fbdea9ef0
>
> 2D graphics backend   Skia/54 a21f10dd8b19c6cb47d07d94d0a0525c16461969
>
> Command Line Args Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --flag-
>
> switches-begin --enable-gpu-rasterization --enable-unsafe-es3-apis
>   --enable-
>
> webgl-draft-extensions --flag-switches-end
>
> Driver Information
>
> Initialization time   0
>
> In-process GPU    true
>
> Sandboxed false
>
> GPU0  VENDOR = 0x1002, DEVICE= 0x6660
>
> GPU1  VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x1916
>
> Optimus   false
>
> AMD switchable    true
>
> Desktop compositing   Aero Glass
>
> Diagonal Monitor Size of \.\DISPLAY1 15.5"
>
> Driver vendor Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
>
> Driver version    16.200.2001.0
>
> Driver date   6-16-2016
>
> Pixel shader version
>
> Vertex shader version
>
> Max. MSAA samples
>
> Machine model name
>
> Machine model version
>
> GL_VENDOR
>
> GL_RENDERER
>
> GL_VERSION
>
> GL_EXTENSIONS
>
> Disabled Extensions
>
> Window system binding vendor
>
> Window system binding version
>
> Window system binding extensions
>
> Direct rendering  Yes
>
> Reset notification strategy   0x0000
>
> GPU process crash count   0
>
> Compositor Information
>
> Tile Update Mode  One-copy
>
> Partial Raster    Enabled
>
> GpuMemoryBuffers Status
>
> ATC   Software only
>
> ATCIA Software only
>
> DXT1  Software only
>
> DXT5  Software only
>
> ETC1  Software only
>
> R_8   Software only
>
> BGR_565   Software only
>
> RGBA_4444 Software only
>
> RGBX_8888 Software only
>
> RGBA_8888 Software only
>
> BGRX_8888 Software only
>
> BGRA_8888 Software only
>
> YVU_420   Software only
>
> YUV_420_BIPLANAR  Software only
>
> UYVY_422  Software only
>
> Diagnostics
>   ... loading ...

**Log Messages**

```
[1268:3756:1107/133435:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(252)] : No suitable EGL configs found.

[1268:3756:1107/133435:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1012)] : eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG

[1268:3756:1107/133435:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(35)] : gl::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed

[1268:3756:1107/133435:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(108)] : Could not create surface for info collection.

[1268:3756:1107/133435:ERROR:gpu_main.cc(506)] : gpu::CollectGraphicsInfo failed (fatal).

GpuProcessHostUIShim: The GPU process exited normally. Everything is okay.
```

Answer (score 30):

Got the same issue, found a post about ignoring the hardware list of compatible materials. So, go to `chrome://flags`, and activate first option:

- Ignorer la liste de rendu logiciel (in french)
- Override software rendering list (english)

https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser

Tell me if it helps !

Comment: It helped for Chrome and Opera. Thank you! In chrome://flags or opera://flags you need to look for tag: #ignore-gpu-blacklist - it is language independent. I think that it will also work for vivaldi and other chrome based browsers.

Comment: "Override software rendering list" fixed my WebGL problem with Chrome 57 on Windows 10.

Comment: Yup.  Worked for me too with my AMD Radeon M7.  I'm just adding this so this page might show up in Google search results for "AMD webgl chrome issue" :-).

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still showing WebGL unavailabe under `chrome://gpu/` after enabling **Override software rendering list** at `chrome://flags/`.

Check further down at `chrome://gpu/` under the topic: **Problems Detected**. If there is a mention about GPU access being disabled:

> GPU process was unable to boot: GPU access is
>   disabled in chrome://settings. Disabled Features: all

Navigate to:

> chrome://settings/ > Advanced > Systems

And enable **Use hardware acceleration**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when using sketchfab! In "Override software rendering list" I selected to show "disable", and everything looks ok now!!

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead